# Stop paying for service after company refuse to end contact even on valid ground

Tags: contract-law, california

So I signup for a service with a 1-year contract. After a year the contact would be renewed on a month to month basis with 1-month notice to terminate the service. I have contacted the company and they refuse to end the contact claim I signed up 2 months ago. The date of the signup is stated in the contact. It is crystal clear that I should be able to terminate the contact. When going through this I noticed that a lot of people are complaining that they are pulling this scammy behavior, so I'm not the only one affected.

So I'm wondering if I can just legally cut off the payment to this company. They have had there noticed delivered if they choose to not accept it is the companies problem right? (All contact was done through email so I have a paper trail proving it all)

Comment: How long has it been since you signed the contract?  You say that they claim it has been 2 months.  How long has it really been?

Comment: It was signed 1st of Janurary 2019.

Comment: So does the "1-month notice to terminate" apply during the first year, or only after you go month to month?  Sounds like you might be on the hook until December 31, 2019.

Comment: Yes, but what I did not mention in the question is that when I signed up I paid last and the first month. So December has already been paid. I can get the exact wording of the contract edited in to the question when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can stop paying. You gave them what they asked for.

Comment: You might want to add that you should record when and how you provided notice, ideally including who you spoke to/emailed with and other details.

Comment: The OP is still within the 1-year contract.  Not sure from the question, but it sounds like the 1-month notice only applies after the year is up.